# Pandas: Convert multiple columns in DataFrame from object to float

Tags: python, pandas

To clean up data I want to convert several columns that should be numeric to numeric. Assignment of multiple columns has no effect.

Minimal (non-)working example.
The column 'S' is a string, 'D' and 'L' should be converted to numeric. The `dtypes` are `object` - as expected

1)

```
x=pd.DataFrame([ ['S',1,5], 
                 ['M',1.4,'10'], 
                 ['L','2.3',14.5]], 
               columns=['S', 'D', 'L'])
x.dtypes
  S    object
  D    object
  L    object
dtype: object
```

2. 

I tried the conversion using `pd.to_numeric` and `astype(float)` on the slice. **It does not work**

```
x.loc[:, ['D','L'] ] = x.loc[:, ['D', 'L']].apply(pd.to_numeric)
x.dtypes
 S    object
 D    object
 L    object
 dtype: object
```

3 Check: creating a new dataframe with the righthand side does work and gives the correct type (float64)

```
x.loc[:, ['D', 'L']].apply(pd.to_numeric).dtypes
D    float64
L    float64
dtype: object
```

4 What **does work** is assigning a *single* column.

```
x.loc[:, 'D' ] = x.loc[:, 'D'].apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

yields the **correct** types for column 'D'.

The weird thing is after assinging a single column with a corrected type the assignment of multiple columns (as in 2) works ?!?

5

```
x.loc[:, ['D','L'] ] = x.loc[:, ['D', 'L']].apply(pd.to_numeric) 
x.dtypes
S     object
D    float64
L    float64
dtype: object
```

I am not sure if it has to do with views vs. copies but even when creating a deep-copy (`copy(deep=True)`) the assignment of a slice with multiple columns has no effect.

**Why** does this not work? and **How** does pandas expect to work with multiple columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the loc and row splice:
x[['D', 'L']] = x[['D', 'L']].apply(pd.to_numeric)

Comment: Thanks, this works. But Why is the ``loc[]`` a problem here?

Answer (score 2):

This one works for me:

```
x[['D', 'L']] = x[['D', 'L']].astype(float)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. But Why is the ``loc[]`` a problem here?